# Failed to start Network Name Resolution on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu can't open. The following errors are produced:

```
Stopped Network Name Resolution.
Systemd-resolved.service : Start request repeated too quickly.
Systemd-resolved.service : Failed with result 'resources'.
Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
```

What should I do?